# Problem with "extra_context" in a login view

Tags: django, authentication, django-class-based-views, django-login

I'm looking at login views rn but have troubles trying to redirect using the "next" variable that I'm trying to assign a value to inside of "extra_context" dictionary. Overriding "extra_context" in a custom view that inherits from "LoginView" also doesn't work. Redirecting with "next_page" or when hardcoding a value for GET's "next" field works fine. Here's my code.

---

**HTML**

```
<form class="" action="{%url 'luecken:login'%}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td>{{form.username}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td>{{form.password}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" name="logInBtn">Log in</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}/">
</form>
```

---

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('c_tests/', include('luecken.urls')),
]
```

---

**luecken/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

# Custom urls
app_name = 'luecken'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name = 'homepage'),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(extra_context={'next':'/c_tests/'}), name='login')
```

**Solved**

Comment: Your code works just fine for me - `next` is correctly passed to the template. There is something that you haven't included in your question that is causing it not to work for you. What value is being rendered for `next` in your case?

Comment: I added project's "urls.py" to the question. So I'm trying to redirect back to homepage after logging in. To be precise, my problem is that 'next' doesn't get passed to the template. I tried testing with {% if next %} but nothing happens. Instead I'm redirected to default "accounts/profile"